# How can I make operations with variables of type Moment in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, momentjs

I have installed moment library in my TypeScript project and when I want to rest two variables of type Moment I get a error on `now` and `then` variables. Here is my code:

```typescript
import moment, { Moment } from "moment";

const now: Moment = moment();
const then: Moment = moment("2022-09-16 22:00:00", "YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss");

const countdown: Moment = moment(then - now);
```

When I rest `then` to `now` is where I get the error.

The error is:
`The left-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number', 'bigint' or an enum type.`

If I put type `any` I don't get any error, but I don't want to do it like that.

I know there is the method `moment().difference()` that can do the same but I want to know if there is the possibility to do it like above.

In JavaScript without TypeScript the operation runs good.

Comment: `moment()` returns an object, not a number that you can perform arithmetic operations on. Use the `moment().difference()` method instead: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/

Comment: It works in JS because of implicit conversion, which TS doesn't allow. You could do e.g. `+then - +now` to explicitly convert the moment objects to numbers. And note all of the React stuff is irrelevant, the [mre] is what you've already included.

Comment: @jonrsharpe That was the solution. Thanks very much! I made `((then as number) - (now as number))` but doesn't worked but I see that with the `+` works. Great!

Comment: Note you should research your error messages, there are loads of posts about this sort of thing already: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Btypescript%5D+The+left-hand+side+of+an+arithmetic+operation+must+be+of+type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works in JS because of implicit conversion, which TS doesn't allow. Doing e.g. `+then - +now` explicitly convert the moment objects to numbers.